# Install shield - set targetdir to c:\Test

Tags: installshield

I'm using Installshield and want to set the destionation folder to **c:\test**.
the problem is that the dialog does not allow it.
What is the solution for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Setup.rul in the OnFirstUIBefore function if I remember correctly and add this lines:

```
// Create a list for system information.
listInfo = ListCreate (STRINGLIST);

// Get the boot drive.
if (GetSystemInfo (BOOTUPDRIVE, nvResult, svResult) < 0) then
    szError = "Couldn't get BOOTUPDRIVE info.";
else
    TARGETDIR = svResult ^ "Test";
endif;
```

This guarantees that if the C:\ is not the boot up drive it will be changed to the boot drive.

Answer (score 2):

Your dialog box looks like an older version of Installshield, but in any case this might help others who are looking to do the same thing.

If you do not want to (or cannot) create the custom destination path (method described in other answers), a simple alternative is setting INSTALLDIR to [WindowsVolume]test.

This installs the tool in C:\test. Of course, if the system does not have a C: drive, it installs it in the available drive.

Answer (score 1):

See:

[Q104964: HOWTO: Creating a Custom Destination Path](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q104964)

BTW, it is possible that the system doesn't have a C: drive.